# Creating graphics for a simple board game in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, mouseevent

I have created a board game in Java that is not different in principle from checkers. It works fine in the console but now I'm trying to create graphics. I have a Piece class, a Tile class that checks if it is empty or occupied by a white or a black checkers piece, a Grid class that keeps track of the tiles in a matrix, and a Game class.

Currently, the game can be played in the Grid class; when we run the Grid class, the user specifies the size of the board in the console and then plays the game by giving the x and y coordinates of the tile that the user wishes to select. What I would like to change is to run the game in the Game class, which is an extension of JPanel and implements MouseListener (code given below). The game board will be a fixed size (I'll begin with 5x5) and I have drawn a picture of a grid which should be in the background of the game. There will be an instance variable (Grid g = new Grid(5,5)). I have also drawn pictures of the different "checkers" pieces which will be used, they should be distributed in the foreground on specific tiles. What I want to happen is that when the user clicks a tile, the checkers pieces move. Ideally, I would do this so that the program sees the coordinates of the place that the mouse clicks (say that the JPanel is 500x500 pixels and the user clicks the pixel with the coordinate (0,500), then we check if (0,500) belongs to some tile, if it doesn't then nothing happens, if it does belong to a tile on the Grid g then g.play(something,something)).

```
            import java.awt.Color;
            import java.awt.FlowLayout;
            import java.awt.Graphics;
            import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
            import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
            import javax.swing.JFrame;
            import javax.swing.JLabel;
            import java.util.*;
            import java.awt.*;
            import java.awt.event.*;
            import java.awt.FlowLayout;
            import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
            import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
            import javax.swing.*;

            public class Game extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

                private Grid g = new Grid(5,5);

                public Game() {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Boardgame");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

                    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.addMouseListener(this);

                }
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        //here we check if the user clicked on a tile, 
    if that happens then we get the x and y-coordinates of the tile and then g.play(x,y)
                }

                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
// we are not really interested in this method or the following 
mouse methods but they are necessary for the mouselistener

                }

                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            public static void main(String args[]) {
                new Game();
            }
        }
```

So in essence, what I would like to do is:

i) Have a background picture (this is easy right?) [update: I have done this by means of using a JLabel, if there is any better way to do it please tell me].

ii) Fix the MouseListener so that the pieces move when a tile is clicked. The only input I require is which tile is to be moved, we don't need to know which piece is supposed to go there.

Any help would be really appreciated and please ask if I can clarify something. This is not for school or anything, just a private project.

Answer (score 5):

You could use **Shape** and attach listeners to catch user actions on the shapes.

> To enable the user to interact with the graphics you display, you need to be able to determine when the user clicks on one of them. The hit method of the Graphics2D class provides a way to easily determine whether a mouse click occurred over a particular Shape object. Alternatively you can get the location of the mouse click and call contains on the Shape to determine whether the click was within the bounds of the Shape.

read on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/user.html

Comment: This looks like what I need to begin with. I will implement this into my code and then see if my other questions will be resolved by this.

Comment: @Sid if you have questions, don't hesitate to ask :). i will do my best to help here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have uploaded my background image (which is just a typical 5x5 board) as a JLabel on the JPanel. I found out that by using e.getX() and e.getY() I can tell where the mouse cursor is located, so I don't need the Shapes (I think). That way I can tell if the user clicked a tile or not. Now, what I'm wondering is i) how do I display the "checkers" pieces on top of my board? Do I set the pieces as JLabels and put them on top of the background picture? ii) How do I make the location of the pieces update on the board when the user has clicked a tile? (Ideally you would see them move.)

Comment: I guess, you could follow your idea to use labels in this manner: [example I once used with labels for c# illustrates the concept and I guess in swing this should be possible too (didn't try personally)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd492159(v=vs.100).aspx), this includes some work with labels set-up. However I would use Graphics2D, draw all the board and figures on the BufferedImage and display the result on the new JLabel(new ImageIcon(resultingImage)). :)

Comment: Hello again! Since you were so helpful, can I ask you another simple question in chat or somewhere? I need to paste some code but the comment box here is too small.

Comment: @Sid i think we can chat in [Java room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java) :). You can paste your code to http://pastie.org/ or http://pastiebin.com/ for example.